# Is 'thread pooling' relevant for Go?

Tags: go, threadpool

Since it is generally very little overhead in terms of memory requirement and setup/tear down cost of a Go routine. Is it relevant even to implement a thread(go routine) worker pool? When would you consider using a thread pool instead of 'spawning' a go routine per request?

Comment: If you are using blocking IO you should consider using thread pool instead of goroutine.

Comment: @ymonad, what do you mean by blocking IO? In Go all IO is blocking, that's kinda the whole point of it's concurrency model. If you mean file IO, which internally is vastly different from network IO, then the problem is not about goroutines at all. It's about actual OS threads waiting for syscalls to return.

Comment: @crecker What I intended was that, as far as using go's network library which is non-blocking, you will get the benefit of M:N thread model of goroutine, however, When you use system call which blocks IO, the go scheduler creates one thread per goroutine, so using thread pool might be an option.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Luje-okL4jI

Comment: @ymonad, the reason I asked is that, from a language perspective, all IO is blocking and your comment is misleading in that context - there is no "if". You're always using blocking IO, even with network IO - Goroutine calls "Read" and blocks. What's going on inside is a completely different thing and may change in the future. But if you're concerned about syscalls, then it has nothing to do with the actual goroutines - they're still cheap. The problem is with OS threads being spawned to wait on syscalls. And it's not limited to IO, all syscalls work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Spawning and keeping lots of goroutines in golang is cheap but it's not free.

Also you should remember that goroutine themselves may be very cheap, but at the same time a lot of memory can be allocated inside of goroutine code. So you may want to limit number of concurrently running goroutines.

You may use semaphore to limit resources.
Another approach (more idiomatic for go) is to use executions pipelines with worker pools. This pattern is very well described in [golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines).

Comment: The book "Concurrency in Go" illustrates this topic well

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's relevant. *db/sql* uses pool of connections to database, because of establishing new connection take time.

Comment: This is slightly off topic - pooling database connections is not quite the same as thread pooling.